# Создать массив из данных файла

Tags: javascript

Есть файл, структура которого выглядит примерно так:

```
33,40,43,45,47,49
34,40,41,45,46,48
36,40,43,45,46,48
15,39,43,44,47,49
35,40,42,45,47,49
...
```

Я пытаюсь загрузить данные файла и записать все что в нем есть в одномерный массив, важно что бы он в итоге был числовой. Есть один вариант, но мне кажется что он неэффективен ибо все можно сделать гораздо проще существующими функциями JS.

Мой вариант выглядит так и не работает ибо сколько всего я не пробовал - выходит либо undefigned или строка. Например я так и не понял как расширять массив(одномерный) другими массивами, что бы при этом его данные стали числовыми.

```js
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
 document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
 var file = e.target.files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(e) {
  var text = e.target.result;
  var newarray = text.split('\n');
  for (i=0; i<newarray.length; i++) {array.concat(newarray[i].split(','));}
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) array[i] = Math.floor((array[i]/50)*100)/100;
  for (i=0; i<array.length-501; i++) {
   array2.push([array.slice(i,i+500), [array[i+501]]]);
  }
 };
   
 reader.readAsText(file);
 });
} else {
 alert('File API is not supported!');
}
```

Ну и после этого я делаю еще один массив на основе данных данного. Это не должно влиять ни на что, кроме как еще раз подчеркнуть, что нужно записать все данные в одномерный массив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить массив такого вида: `[33, 40, 43, 45, ...]`? Тогда достаточно двух вложенных циклов и двух вызовов [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), примерно как вы и делали. Работает это примерно так:

1. Пихаем содержимое файла в строку.
2. Прогоняем эту строку через [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), чтобы убрать перенос строки в конце файла.
3. Эту самую строку, содержащую файл, разбиваем на множество подстрок и превращаем в массив, в качестве разделителя используя символ переноса строки.
4. Каждую подстроку разделяем еще раз, используя в качестве разделителя запятую.
5. Проходимся по каждому числу и пушим в конечный массив.

```js
let file = `33,40,43,45,47,49
34,40,41,45,46,48
36,40,43,45,46,48
15,39,43,44,47,49
35,40,42,45,47,49`;

file = file.trim();

let rows = file.split("\n");
let flatArray = [];

for (let row in rows) {
  items = rows[row].split(',');

  for (let item in items) {
    flatArray.push(parseInt(items[item]));
  }
}

console.log(flatArray);
```

Вместо `for...in` можете также использовать [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (ES6) или [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - как вам удобно.

Comment: `Array#map` тут больше подошёл бы.

Comment: @Other интересно. Я слышал о нем раньше, а сейчас почитал, полезная штука :) Спасибо!